# Get string from word bookmark back to excel after sending the string to the bookmark

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

**I try to achieve the following thing:**
Copy string elements from an excel cell to a bookmark in word. There a user can modify the strings and can after modification send the strings back to excel.

**My Problem:**
I can copy the strings over to the bookmarks (bookmars are set as enclosing bookmarks in word, means that i have a just written 'abc' where the bookmark should be, marked 'abc' and pressed bookmark.) the bookmarks are still there after copying the text but when I try to write the strings at the bookmarks back to excel the .Range-Object is empty.

**My Question:**
Could anyone help me accomlish my goal to get the strings back from the bookmarks to excel. Therefore I just need the string in an object or so. A msgbox(the_string) is enought I can put it then to the place in excel where it belongs.

Here is my code:

```
 Sub BM(Step As Byte)
    Dim docApp As Word.Application
    Dim CurrentDoc As Word.Document

    Set docApp = GetObject(, "word.application")
    Set CurrentDoc = docApp.ActiveDocument

    CurrentDoc.Bookmarks(Step & "Number").Range.Select

    Dim objBMRange_pos As Word.Range
    Set objBMRange_pos = CurrentDoc.Bookmarks(Step & "Number").Range

    Dim oData As dataobject

    Set oData = New dataobject

    oData.SetText ""
    'The function Check_A delivers the string from excel cells
    oData.SetText Check_A(Step, "Number")
    oData.PutInClipboard

    oData.GetFromClipboard
    CurrentDoc.Bookmarks(Step & "Number").Range.Text = oData.GetText
    'CurrentDoc.Parent.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    'Re-new the bookmarks
    CurrentDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=(Step & "Number"), Range:=objBMRange_pos
    Debug.Print CurrentDoc.Bookmarks(Step & "Number").Range.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found the answer by myself.

```
oData.PutInClipboard
    oData.GetFromClipboard
    CurrentDoc.Bookmarks(Step & "Number").Range.InsertBefore oData.GetText
    Debug.Print (CurrentDoc.Bookmarks(Step & "Number").Range.Text)
```

Did the trick. You just have to delete the characters you used for the Enclosing Bookmark before.

Here we have a good source: [VBA & Bookmarks](http://www.bettersolutions.com/word/WUD983/LO749366512.htm)